# Textbook package compatible with examdoc

Tags: exam

I really like the `examdoc` class.  I almost always use it to create exams, tests, ...
However...
I'd like to make a textbook.  In it should be several exercises, with (preferably) their solutions in an appendix.
I encounter following problems:

1. I'm using `\documentclass{book}` for the textbook.  I'd like to be able to copy-paste questions and solutions to a `\documentclass{exam}`.  I already tried to make my own `.sty` file:

   ```
   \ProvidesPackage{oefeningen}

   \newenvironment{questions}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
   \newcommand{\question}{\item}
   \newenvironment{parts}{%
   \let\oldpart=\part
   \renewcommand{\part}{\item}
   \begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}\renewcommand{\part}{\oldpart}}
   ```

   but that doesn't seem to do the trick...  (it doesn't compile and I still don't have a clue how to cope with the solution-environment)
2. I don't know how to display the solutions in a seperate appendix, instead of directly after each question...

I'm quite a newbie on writing classes, packages, or macros but any help will be appreciated.  I browsed a lot of forums, too, but imho other answers don't provide the functionality I'd like.  (but I'd happily be corrected)

sort of mwe:

i have this `exam` document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,answers]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Main question goes here
\begin{parts}
\part $1+1=$
\begin{solution}
2
\end{solution}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: what examdoc does]

what i'd like to do (but what doesn't work!) is something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\question Main question goes here
\begin{parts}
\part $1+1=$
\begin{solution}
2
\end{solution}
\end{parts}

\section{solutions}
%command to display list of solutions, optimally organised by section/chapter

\end{document}
```

resulting in something like this

[image: how thinks should look as a textbook]

This way I'd be able to copy-paste questions to/from textbook to re-use them on exams...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: By browsing more, i found the package exsheets, that almost does the trick.  i could easily adapt the `examdoc` class from `\question` to `\begin{question}\end{question}` by using `\newevironment`, so that works out.  But unfortunately, `exsheets` doesn't provide `\begin{parts}`...

Comment: i added something mwe-like...

Comment: This is not going to work with `exsheets` the way you want. The way `exsheets` is designed one can only add a solution to a _whole_ question.

Comment: Of course the easiest way would be to use `exsheets` both for the textbook and the exams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>major edit -> new answer:</sub>

#### The Goal

Writing a textbook using the `exsheets` package and be able to copy & paste the exercises and solutions as they are in a document using the `exam` class for creating exams.

#### Requirements

- The `exsheets` package has no `parts` environment. It needs to be defined so it can be used with the same syntax as required by `exam`.
- a `solution` environment should be available to be used once or more for a question. For this `exsheets`' own `solution` environment needs to be redefined. This also requires a suitable replacement for the environment so `exsheets` can still save solutions to print them later in the textbook.
- adapt `exsheets`' `question` environment in the `exam` document.

#### The Definitions

- **The `parts` Environment:**
  Since in the textbook no points need to be assigned to questions a simple wrapper for `enumerate` will do. We will use `enumitem` because it's comfortable.

  ```
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \newenvironment{parts}{%
    \renewcommand*\part[1][]{\item}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  }{\end{enumerate}}
  ```
- **Redefinition of the `solution` Environment:**
  The first thing we do is create a new question/solution pair for `exsheets`. This will provide a replacement for the original `solution`. *This requires `exsheets` version 0.3 which should be on CTAN in a week or so. The beta version [can be downloaded here](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/overview).*

  ```
  \NewQuSolPair{Question}{Solution}
  ```

  The following is a little bit longer. The goal will be to define `solution` in a way that will store the solution for `exsheets`. The manual way would be to write the solution a second time in the newly defined `Solution` environment:

  ```
  \begin{Question}
  Main question goes here
  \begin{parts}
  \part $1+1=$
  \begin{solution}
   $2$
  \end{solution}
  \end{parts}
  \end{Question}
  % the following should be unnecessary:
  \begin{Solution}
  \begin{parts}
  \part $1+1=$
  \end{parts}
  \end{Solution}
  ```

  Since I don't have a perfect solution for the automization I'll present the basic solution that requires the double input first.

  ```
  \usepackage{environ}
  \makeatletter
  % no idea why these are necessary:
  \def\env@solution@save@env{}
  \def\env@solution@process{}
  % the actual redefinition into a dummy environment
  % that gobbles its body:
  \RenewEnviron{solution}{}
  \makeatother
  ```

#### The Documents

Now the textbook can look like this:

```
% this is textbook.tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newenvironment{parts}{%
  \renewcommand*\part[1][]{\item}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}

\NewQuSolPair{Question}{Solution}

\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\def\env@solution@save@env{}
\def\env@solution@process{}
\RenewEnviron{solution}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\section{questions}\exlabel{sec:questions:foo}

\begin{Question}
Main question goes here
\begin{parts}
\part $1+1=$
\begin{solution}
 $2$
\end{solution}
\part $8-3=$
\begin{solution}
 $5$
\end{solution}
\end{parts}
\end{Question}
\begin{Solution}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item $2$
 \item $5$
\end{enumerate*}
\end{Solution}

\begin{Question}
Another question.
\begin{solution}
 Another answer.
\end{solution}
\end{Question}
\begin{Solution}
 Another answer
\end{Solution}

\section{solutions}
\printsolutions[section=\S{sec:questions:foo}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The corresponding exam:

```
% this is exam.tex
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\newenvironment{Question}{\question}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\begin{Question}
Main question goes here
\begin{parts}
\part $1+1=$
\begin{solution}
 $2$
\end{solution}
\part $8-3=$
\begin{solution}
 $5$
\end{solution}
\end{parts}
\end{Question}

\begin{Question}
Another question.
\begin{solution}
 Another answer.
\end{solution}
\end{Question}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Preliminary Attempt to avoid Double Input of Solutions

The following definition of the `solution` environment tries to automate things but has some obvious shortcomings. Flexibility in creating the solutions is mainly lost.

Every call of `solution` within a question will save its body and at the end of the `Question` environment a `Solution` environment will automatically called if the `solution` env has been used. In order to do this comfortably the `etoolbox` package is used:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,environ}
\makeatletter
\def\addto@solution{}
\def\env@solution@save@env{}
\def\env@solution@process{}
\RenewEnviron{solution}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\BODY}{}
    {%
      \xdef\addto@solution
        {%
          \expandonce\addto@solution
          \ifnum\value{enumi}>0\theenumi\space\fi
          \expandonce\BODY\space
        }%
    }}
\AtBeginEnvironment{Question}{\gdef\addto@solution{}}
\AtEndEnvironment{Question}{%
  \ifdefvoid\addto@solution{}
    {\begin{Solution}\addto@solution\end{Solution}}%
}
```

With this the `textbook.tex` now looks as follows:

```
% this is textbook.tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{parts}{%
  \renewcommand*\part[1][]{\item}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}

\NewQuSolPair{Question}{Solution}

\usepackage{etoolbox,environ}
\makeatletter
\def\addto@solution{}
\def\env@solution@save@env{}
\def\env@solution@process{}
\RenewEnviron{solution}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\BODY}{}
    {%
      \xdef\addto@solution
        {%
          \expandonce\addto@solution
          \ifnum\value{enumi}>0\theenumi\space\fi
          \expandonce\BODY\space
        }%
    }}
\AtBeginEnvironment{Question}{\gdef\addto@solution{}}
\AtEndEnvironment{Question}{%
  \ifdefvoid\addto@solution{}
    {\begin{Solution}\addto@solution\end{Solution}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\section{questions}\exlabel{sec:questions:foo}

\begin{Question}
Main question goes here
\begin{parts}
\part $1+1=$
\begin{solution}
 $2$
\end{solution}
\part $8-3=$
\begin{solution}
 $5$
\end{solution}
\end{parts}
\end{Question}

\begin{Question}
Another question.
\begin{solution}
 And another answer.
\end{solution}
\end{Question}

\section{solutions}
\printsolutions[section=\S{sec:questions:foo}]

\end{document}
```

The result looks the same as above.

---

<sub>original answer:</sub>

You are saying in the comments that [`exsheets`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) would do the trick for you if it had a `parts` environment. If this really is the only thing you're missing: it could easily be defined.

I'm assuming that in the textbook you do not want to assign points to the exercises so the only thing needed is a simple wrapper for an `enumerate` environment. I'm using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to format the labels. The redefinition of `\part` should be kept local since you might want to divide the textbook into parts.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{headings-format=\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{parts}{%
  \renewcommand*\part[1][]{\item}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}
\part{A demonstration}
\begin{question}
 Why is there air?
\end{question}

\begin{question}
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
 \part Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
 \part Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The corresponding `exam` document:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

% the following part is the same as in the other document:
\begin{question}
 Why is there air?
\end{question}

\begin{question}
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
 \part Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
 \part Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}
\end{question}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine concerning the missing `parts` environment.  Thanks a lot, textbook finally compiles...  Alas, this doesn't handle the solutions to the parts of a question.  or at least i don't think they do?

Comment: Why not? The `parts` environment can be used inside the `solution` environment as well.

Comment: but having `solutions` inside that `parts` environment wouldn't be a good idea?

Comment: This won't work the way `exsheets` is designed. I'm sorry. There may be only one `solution` environment per `question` environment and it should be placed _after_ the question.

Comment: I might have a workaround... This'll has to wait until tonight, though.

Comment: @TomDierckx See my edited answer

Comment: fantastic.  i'm working with the new ideas/aditional code, and... so far, so good