# Write the value of enumerate to output file

Tags: enumerate, write

I would like to save the present value of an enumeration into an output file. Using information from another question I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\collectSolutions}{\immediate\openout\tempfile=solutions.tex}

\newwrite\tempfile

\newcommand{\solution}[1]{\immediate\write\tempfile{\theenumi\theenumii\theenumiii:\unexpanded{#1}}}

\newcommand{\printSolutions}{%
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\noindent\input{solutions}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\collectSolutions

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Text 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Part Q 1 \solution{A}
      \item Part Q 1 \solution{B}
      \item Part Q 1 \solution{\mbox{$solution$}}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Another Q \solution{D}
\end{enumerate}

\printSolutions

\end{document}
```

The out put lists the final question as being 2c. I assume this is because the enumii counter is not reset until this level is restarted. All the same, how can I obtain the 1a, 1b, 1c, 2 in the final list from \printSolutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define control sequences based on the depths; one could use `\p@enumi`, `\p@enumii` and `\p@enumiii`, but the result would depend on the class; in this way, instead, you can choose your own representation.

The key is that the macro `\@enumctr` records the current enumeration counter name; thus with

```
\csname sol@\@enumctr\endcsname
```

we access `\sol@enumi`, `\sol@enumii` or `\sol@enumiii` without manual intervention. Adjust the meaning of these macros to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\solutions@file
\newcommand{\collectSolutions}{\immediate\openout\solutions@file=\jobname.sol}
\newcommand{\sol@enumi}{\theenumi}
\newcommand{\sol@enumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii}
\newcommand{\sol@enumiii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii}
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\solutions@file{%
    \csname sol@\@enumctr\endcsname: \unexpanded{#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\printSolutions}{%
  \immediate\closeout\solutions@file
  \noindent\input{\jobname.sol}
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\collectSolutions

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Text 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Part Q 1 \solution{A}
      \item Part Q 1 \solution{B}
      \item Part Q 1 \solution{C}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Another Q \solution{D}
\end{enumerate}

\printSolutions

\end{document}
```

This is the contents of the "solutions" file:

```
1.a: A
1.b: B
1.c: C
2: D
```

I prefer not to give a "fixed" name to the output file, so as not to clobber existing files. With the proposed macros, the output file will have the same name as the main LaTeX file with extension `.sol`.

---

If you want to add formatting instructions for writing in the `.sol` file, then you have two ways.

### First method

```
\newcommand{\sol@enumi}{\noexpand\textbf{\theenumi}}
```

will not expand `\textbf` when the writing operation takes place. Every "unsafe" macro should be preceded by `\noexpand` (not `\theenumi`, which we *want* to be expanded right away).

### Second method

Define a `\protected@immediatewrite` macro similar to `\protected@write`:

```
\makeatletter
\newwrite\solutions@file
\newcommand{\collectSolutions}{\immediate\openout\solutions@file=\jobname.sol}
\newcommand{\sol@enumi}{\textbf{\theenumi}}
\newcommand{\sol@enumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii}
\newcommand{\sol@enumiii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii}

\newcommand{\protected@immediatewrite}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\thepage\relax
    #2% additional settings
    \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}\reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \protected@immediatewrite\solutions@file{}{\csname sol@\@enumctr\endcsname: \unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\printSolutions}{%
  \immediate\closeout\solutions@file
  \noindent\input{\jobname.sol}
}
\makeatother
```

The rest of the file can be the same as before.

Comment: +1. I was about to post a solution that used a loop to concatenate `\theenum...` based on the `\@enumdepth`, but this solution seems cleaner.

Comment: This works great. A question though: you say ``Adjust the meaning of these macros to suit your needs.'' so I tried to make the question number bold, so I did `\textbf{\theenumi}` but this didn't work.

Comment: @Geoff No, formatting instructions must be protected against expansion. I'll add a more robust way for this.

Comment: @egreg Thx for the update. The first method works, the second method hits problems when there is a box (an mbox in my case) within the \solution input.

Comment: @Geoff Please, add some example cases.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I posted into my original minimal example a minimal extension.

Comment: @Geoff You'd get the same with `\mbox` in section titles, for instance, but with the difference that the `.aux` file is read under `\makeatletter`. Reinstate `\unexpanded` also in the second solution; but some care (with `\noexpand` or `\protect`) should be taken for the "number part".

Comment: @egreg I don't know what I'm supposed to do with _reinstate \unexpanded_. It doesn't matter, the first method works. I am very thankful for your expert assistance.

Comment: @Geoff see the edited answer