# Creating a question-solution capability

Tags: enumerate, exercises, write

I am trying to modify a question-solution capability that was answered brilliantly a while back [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91446/11162). After each question text, one can freely use `\solution` to keep the solution directly with the question text. The solutions are stored in a .sol file through the command `\collectSolutions` and can be accessed in the document through `\printSolutions`. The code below is thanks to David Carlisle and works a charm (perhaps it should be a package). This question is about the fine tuning.

The code below will return the numbering of the solutions as:
1: 2a: b: c: 3ai: ii: 3b: 4:

I would like it to return:
1: 2a: b: c: 3ai: ii: b: 4:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\solutions@file
\newcommand{\collectSolutions}{\immediate\openout\solutions@file=\jobname.sol}
\newcommand{\sol@enumi}{{\theenumi}}
\newcommand{\sol@enumii}{{\theenumi.}\theenumii}
\newcommand{\sol@enumiii}{{\theenumi.\theenumii.}\theenumiii}
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\solutions@file{%
    \noexpand\solsep\csname sol@\@enumctr\endcsname: \unexpanded{#1\ignorespaces}%
  }%
}

\def\solsep{\afterassignment\@solsep\def\@tempa}

\def\@solsep{%
\ifx\@tempa\sol@lastsec,
\else
\global\let\sol@lastsec\@tempa
\sol@stop\gdef\sol@stop{. }%
\textbf{\@tempa}
\fi
}

\newcommand{\printSolutions}{%
  \let\sol@stop\@empty
  \gdef\sol@lastsec{0.}%
  \immediate\closeout\solutions@file
  \noindent\input{\jobname.sol}\sol@stop
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\collectSolutions

\begin{enumerate}
\item Question text \solution{Ans}
\item Question text 
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans}
\end{enumerate}
\item Another Q
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Part Q
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Part Q \solution{Ans}
        \item Part Q \solution{Ans}
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans}
\end{enumerate}
\item Question text \solution{Ans}
\end{enumerate}

\printSolutions
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know the exsheets package?

Comment: When I first looked at `exsheets` I wasn't able to find out how to keep solutions directly embedded next to the question text.

Comment: what do you mean by `embedded next to the question text` exactly?

Comment: Look at the (not so) MWE above: One simply writes text for the question and then you put in a `\solution{answer text}`. Personally I find it very elegant.

Comment: Do you know about the `probsoln` package? Or you can [use a combination of `datatool` and `datatooltk`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatoolexam.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to rewrite the macro `\sol@enumiii` to group the two higher prefixes separately.  So

```
\newcommand{\sol@enumiii}{{\theenumi.}{\theenumii.}\theenumiii}
```

with two internal groups instead of the one group `{\theenumi.\theeunmii.}`.  The code below also fixes the extraneous space before `:` in the output of your MWE.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\solutions@file
\newcommand{\collectSolutions}{\immediate\openout\solutions@file=\jobname.sol}
\newcommand{\sol@enumi}{{\theenumi}}
\newcommand{\sol@enumii}{{\theenumi.}\theenumii}
\newcommand{\sol@enumiii}{{\theenumi.}{\theenumii.}\theenumiii}
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\solutions@file{%
    \noexpand\solsep\csname sol@\@enumctr\endcsname: \unexpanded{#1\ignorespaces}%
  }%
}

\def\solsep{\afterassignment\@solsep\def\@tempa}

\def\@solsep{%
\ifx\@tempa\sol@lastsec,
\else
\global\let\sol@lastsec\@tempa
\sol@stop\gdef\sol@stop{. }%
\textbf{\@tempa}%
\fi
}

\newcommand{\printSolutions}{%
  \let\sol@stop\@empty
  \gdef\sol@lastsec{0.}%
  \immediate\closeout\solutions@file
  \noindent\input{\jobname.sol}\sol@stop
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\collectSolutions

\begin{enumerate}
\item Question text \solution{Ans one}
\item Question text
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans two A}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans two B}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans two C}
\end{enumerate}
\item Another Q
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Part Q
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Part Q \solution{Ans three A one}
        \item Part Q \solution{Ans three A two}
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Part Q \solution{Ans three B}
  \item Part Q
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Part Q \solution{Ans three C one}
    \item Part Q \solution{Ans three C two}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item Question text \solution{Ans four}
\end{enumerate}

\printSolutions
\end{document}
```