# How to \write content with backslashes to a file?

Tags: write

The following MWE works as I expect but when I make certain changes I get errors:

1. If I introduce say `\textbf{something}` within a `\solution{}` say `\solution{\textbf{xx}}`.
2. If I change `\theenumi` to `\textbf{\theenumi}`

Probably both issues are the same problem.

The MWE below is based on the work from [Write the value of enumerate to output file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88200/11162).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
 \newwrite\solutions@file
 \newcommand{\collectSolutions}{\immediate\openout\solutions@file=\jobname.sol}
 \newcommand{\solution}[1]{\immediate\write\solutions@file{\theenumi #1}}
 \newcommand\printSolutions{\immediate\closeout\solutions@file{\input{\jobname.sol}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\collectSolutions

\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello \solution{xx}
    \item hello \solution{xx}
    \item hello \solution{xx}
\end{enumerate}

\printSolutions
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\solution{\noexpand\textbf{xx}}`

Comment: @koleygr This does indeed work but since I need xx to represent any latex code I don't want to have to noexpand every \ . Perhaps this can be done in general? I tried it in the definition of `\solution` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try  `\newcommand{\solution}[1]{\immediate\write\solutions@file{\theenumi \unexpanded{#1}}}`

Comment: Ooh that seemed to work! I then did `\noexpand\textbf\theenumi\unexpanded{#1}}` and it solved both of my questions!

Comment: I tested too and show that ... Thus... removed the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has to be expanded when will be printed through `\printSolutions` command.

So, try:

```
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{\immediate\write\solutions@file{\theenumi \unexpanded{#1}}}
```

This way the content of the file will be expanded at the time that will be "input"-ed by the command `\printSolutions`.

**Edit:** As you found out, `\noexpand` is also needed to keep the `\theenumi` value like:

```
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{\immediate\write\solutions@file{\noexpand\textbf{\theenumi} \unexpanded{#1}}}
```

Comment: I like this. My final comment above combined both of your ideas. It's confusing that in one case the solution is `\noexpand` and the other it is `\unexpanded`.

Comment: Yes ... I thought for a minute that you could add `\theenumi` inside the `\unexpanded` command but it will expand only with the last value of it.