# How to include exam class features in book class

Tags: document-classes, exam

I am currently writing up notes using the `book` class with three parts, one for lecturers notes, one for mine, and one for practice questions. I love the `exam` class for formatting questions, but I want the book class for all the formatting. Is there some way to integrate the `question` environment into this book class without just copying the needed parts from `exam.cls` or `book.cls` into my document/into a new package?

```
\documentclass{book} % I want it formatted like a book
%\documentclass[answers]{exam} % But have questions formatted like exam

\begin{document}
\title{My Revision Book}
\maketitle

\part{Notes}

% 'normal' LaTeX

\part{Practice questions/past exam papers}
\begin{questions}
\question
How long is a piece of string

\begin{solution}
This long $\leftarrow\rightarrow$ (not to scale).
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an aswer: maybe the [`exsheets`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) package might be an alternative for you?

Comment: You might consider looking at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78458/textbook-package-compatible-with-examdoc).  I think some of the comments/answer could help you out as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `question` and `solution` environments to behave *exactly* like they do in the [`exam`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/exam) document class then you'll need to copy the relevant code from `exam.cls`.

However, if you just want something that looks similar, then you could define your own environment, perhaps something like the following, which uses the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) to do the hard work:

```
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions]{label=\arabic*.}
\newcommand{\question}{\item}
```

Similarly, you can define your own `solution` environment:

```
\newenvironment{solution}{ {\bfseries Solution}:}{}
```

Of course, you could get more adventurous by using a `theorem` package, e.g [`amsthm`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsthm) if you wanted more formatting.

Finally, another idea is to simply include the `pdf` version of your previous exams using the [`pdfpages`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages), in which case you don't need to worry about these environments at all!

Here's a complete MWE to build from:

```
\documentclass{book} % I want it formatted like a book
%\documentclass[answers]{exam} % But have questions formatted like exam
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions]{label=\arabic*.}
\newcommand{\question}{\item}

\newenvironment{solution}{ {\bfseries Solution}:}{}

\begin{document}
\title{My Revision Book}
\maketitle

\part{Notes}

% 'normal' LaTeX

\part{Practice questions/past exam papers}
\begin{questions}
\question
How long is a piece of string

\begin{solution}
This long $\leftarrow\rightarrow$ (not to scale).
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```